# Model binding after post-back have DateTime properties as NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, datetime-format

My ASP.NET MVC view model has datetime properties like:

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "yyyyMMdd")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

My controllers action has:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult OnCreate(MyViewModel model) 
{

}
```

My properties are do get binded, expect for the datetime properties.

I am entering dates like:

```
19500125
```

Which is 1950, Janurary 25th which is what my date format is set to: yyyyMMdd

If I do the following this works:

```
            DateTime dateOfBirth;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Request["User.dateOfBirth"], "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None, out dateOfBirth))
            {
                model.User.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            }
```

But the above is not using the built-in binding and isn't the correct way to do things.

Any clues why the binding for datetime isnt' working?

Comment: Upvote, always had this problem, never managed to make it work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any clues why the binding for datetime isnt' working?

It is working as intended.  The default ModelBinder only binds to specific datetime formats.  I think the problem is that you are assuming that the `DisplayFormatAttribute` has some affect on the ModelBinder.  As the attribute states, it is only for Display Format, not for model binding.  If you have a custom DateTime format (which you do) then you'll need to write a [custom DateTime model binder](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) to bind it.